# C# and PowerPoint 2010 integration

Tags: c#, ms-office, powerpoint

I'm making "something" (I don't know how to define it yet), and what does is create a `pptx` presentation and some slides... but I'm facing some problems: I can't change the background color/image of my slides and textboxes... and I can't figure it out... Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm trying to answer your question, but I'm facing some problems. Are you trying to change the background color of your slides from C#, via Office Interop, or are you wanting to do this in PowerPoint? And where are the textboxes? How do you get textboxes on a PowerPoint slide?

Comment: from c#, i want to build a program that "control" powerpoint... like a API... the elements (Shape) are created as the user requests... dont worry about where are them... i have them... i will know where they are... i have the pointers... TKS!

Comment: There aren't any pointers.  Please show us your code.

Comment: here it is: public void CreateNewSlide(Presentation p, int index) { Slide newSlide = p.Slides.AddSlide(index, p.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts[0]); //change the background image of newSlide ? //add a textbox Shape newTextBox = newSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal,0,0,150,75); //set the text inside newTextBox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text="Hello world!!!"; //set the backgroundcolor ? }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you are probably missing with regards to setting colors of objects on your slides is that COM Interop thinks about colors slightly differently than what you may be used to in the .NET Framework.

In the .NET Framework, we represent colors using the aptly-named [`Color` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx), which encapsulates values for the alpha channel of the color, and its red, green, and blue components. However, COM Interop represents colors as an `Integer` value, in the format `BGR`. That means that the component values for red, green, and blue are actually stored as blue, green, and red.

However, the .NET Framework provides an easy, built-in way to convert between these two color formats: the [`ColorTranslator.ToOle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.toole.aspx) and [`ColorTranslator.FromOle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.fromole.aspx) methods. So, you should be able to change the background color of your PowerPoint slide using the following code:

```
//Create a color
Color myBackgroundColor = Color.LimeGreen;

//Translate to an OLE color
int oleColor = ColorTranslator.ToOle(myBackgroundColor);

//Set the background color of the slide
mySlide.Background.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = oleColor;
```

Conversely, to retrieve the current background color as a .NET color, you'll have to do the opposite:

```
//Get the current background color of the slide
int oleColor = mySlide.Background.Fill.ForeColor.RGB;

//Translate to a .NET Color
color myBackgroundColor = ColorTranslator.FromOle(oleColor);
```

And, of course, if you want to set the foreground (fill) color of a shape, you can simply set its `ForeColor` property, like so:

```
//Create a color
Color myForegroundColor = Color.Aqua;

//Translate to an OLE color
int oleColor = ColorTranslator.ToOle(myForegroundColor );

//Set the foreground color of a shape
myShape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = oleColor;
```

Comment: well, it does work for textboxes and pictures... but it does not work for slide background... tks anyway! you were very helpfull!!!

Comment: I'm sorry. I believe you want `ForeColor` to set the slide background as well. `BackColor` is only used for gradients, patterned fills, etc. I've updated my answer.

Comment: yeah... its not working... its not changing, but its not returning an exception or anything else for that matter...

Comment: @Leonardo: If you edit your original question and post the code you're trying to use, maybe I can get a better idea of what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue until I discovered that you need to set slide.FollowMasterBackground to false:

```
Slide slide = presentation.Slides.AddSlide(presentation.Slides.Count + 1, layout);
slide.FollowMasterBackground = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
slide.Background.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.DarkBlue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... in order to change the background of a slide u must first call the method Fill.Background() before changing the color/picture!!! tks everyone for the help